# Rebuild pagination on view after unset

Tags: paging, views

I have a view who display several nodes (more than 10 000), and I display 100 nodes by pages.
With a `HOOK_views_pre_render(&$view)` I browse all the results `$view->result` and I unset the nodes which I haven't access with a personnal function like this :

```
if (!empty($view->result)) {
    if ($view->name == 'vdocuments' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
        foreach ($view->result as $key => $lineView) {
            if (!empty($lineView->nid)) {
                $lineAllowed = _isNodeAllowedToUser($lineView->nid);
                if (empty($lineAllowed) || !$lineAllowed) {
                    //$counter++;
                    unset($view->result[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My first question concern this code. Is there a better method to remove some results in my wiew (I need to use my check function) ? I tried to alter the query of the view and check the NID allowed in a filter, but there is too much NID to remove for certain users.

So, the code above remove all the bad nodes in the page i'm viewing, but all the pagination is destroyed, on several pages I have empty results.

I found this page https://www.drupal.org/node/953072#comment-6317230 but the `update_page_info` doesn't work really good.

Is there a solution to get all the nodes "allowed" and calculate the pagination with the rest of the nodes after the unset ?

thanks

Comment: I tried to unset my results in `HOOK_views_post_execute` like this post said http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95448/update-views-result-after-unset-in-views-pre-render but this not working.. Nobody have an solution for the problem ?

Comment: A little up for my post because I haven't found any solutions since november.